# I cant build a border around the array in this program Game of Life in C language

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I have the simulation Game of Life in C language as my assignment. I've tried and failed many times to build a border of asterisks around the final printed array. Also I've used a few goto statements, which caused another problem: if i restart the game from the menu the last generating function namely "generation_printer" does not exit and as a result two patters appear on the grid instead of one.This is my progress so far

```
#include "stdio.h" //for all basic functions
#include "stdlib.h"//for exit function
#include "time.h" //for random seed
#include "windows.h" //
#include "conio.h" //
#define scanf_s scanf

void neighbour_manager();//custom function to calculate neighbours and make a cell alive or dead accordingly
void generation_printer();//custom function to print the generations after selecting seed type

//initializing all variables
int generation;
char fill_char;
char array[35][85];
char array1[35][85];
char live = '+';
char dead = ' ';
char n;
//SEEDS
char block[2][2] = {{'+','+'}, {'+','+'}};
char boat[3][3] = {{'+','+',' '}, {'+',' ','+'}, {' ','+',' '}};
char loaf[4][4] = {{' ','+','+',' '},{'+', ' ', ' ', '+'},{' ', '+', ' ', '+'},{' ', ' ', '+', ' '}};
char beehive[3][4] = {{' ','+','+',' '},{'+', ' ', ' ', '+'},{' ', '+', '+', ' '}};
char blinker[1][3] = {{'+', '+','+'}};
char beacon[4][4] = {{'+','+',' ',' '},{'+',' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' ','+'},{' ',' ','+','+'}};
char toad[2][4] = {{' ','+','+','+'},{'+','+','+',' '}};
char pulsar[15][15] = {
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {'+','+','+',' ',' ','+','+',' ','+','+',' ',' ','+','+','+'},
                           {' ',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ',' '},
                           {'+','+','+',' ',' ','+','+',' ','+','+',' ',' ','+','+','+'},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ','+','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                           {' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+',' ',' ',' ',' '}
                          };
char glider[3][3] = {{' ','+',' '},{' ',' ','+'},{'+','+','+'}};
char spaceship[4][5] = {{'+',' ',' ','+',' '},{' ',' ',' ',' ','+'},{'+',' ',' ',' ','+'},{' ','+','+','+','+',}};
char gosper_glider_gun[15][38] = {
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' ', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }
                                 };


//main function starts here
int main(void)
{
    system("title CONWAY'S GAME OF LIFE");//to change the console title
    _flushall();//to remove garbage values
    printf("\t\t\t\t\tWelcome to Conway's Game of Life\n");//welcome note
    Sleep(2000);//for dramatic purposes
    system("cls");
    printf("Please make sure the console is maximized for optimal simulation.");//whole grid is not visible if console is not maximized
    Sleep(2000);//to create a pause to maximize screen before proceeding
    start:
    system("cls");
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int a = 0, b = 0, seed_type = 0;
    printf("Select the seed type\nSTILL LIFE PATTERNS\nEnter 1 for Block \nEnter 2 for Loaf \nEnter 3 for Boat\nEnter 4 for Beehive\n\nOSCILLATORS\nEnter 5 for Blinker\nEnter 6 for Beacon\nEnter 7 for Toad\nEnter 8 for Pulsar\n\nGLIDERS AND SPACSHIPS\nEnter 9 for Glider\nEnter 10 for Spaceship\n\nGOSPER GLIDER GUN\nEnter 11 for Gosper Glider Gun\nYour choice: ");
    retake_seed_type: //For invalid choice

            scanf_s("%d", &seed_type);

    srand(time(NULL));
    a = 1 + rand() % 35;
    b = 1 + rand() % 85;
    switch (seed_type)
    {
    case 1: //for block
        for (i = a; i < a + 2; i++){
            for (j = b; j < b + 2; j++){

                array[i][j] = block[i - a][j - b];
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2://for loaf
        for (i = a; i <a + 4; i++){
            for (j = b; j <b + 4; j++){

                array[i][j] = loaf[i - a][j - b];
            }
        }
        break;
    case 3://for boat
        for (i = a; i <a + 3; i++){
            for (j = b; j <b + 3; j++){

                array[i][j] = boat[i - a][j - b];
            }
        }
        break;
    case 4://beehive
        for(i = a; i <a + 3; i++){
          for(j = b; j <b + 4; j++){
            array[i][j] = beehive[i-a][j-b];
          }
        }
        break;
    case 5://blinker
        for(i=a;i<a+1;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+3;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = blinker[i-a][j-b];
          }
        }
        break;
    case 6://beacon
        for(i=a;i<a+4;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+4;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = beacon[i-a][j-b];
          }
        }
        break;
    case 7://Toad
        for(i=a;i<a+2;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+4;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = toad[i-a][j-b];
          }
        }
        break;
    case 8://Pulsar
        for(i=a;i<a+15;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+15;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = pulsar[i-a][j-b];
          }
        }
        break;
        case 9://glider
        for(i=a;i<a+3;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+3;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = glider[i-a][j-b];
          }
        }
        break;
        case 10://spaceship
        for(i=a;i<a+4;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+5;j++){
            array[i%35][j%85] = spaceship[i-a][j-b];
          }
        }
        break;
        case 11://gosper glider gun
        for(i=a;i<a+15;i++){
          for(j=b;j<b+38;j++){
            array[i][j] = gosper_glider_gun[i-a][j-b];
          }
        }
        break;

    default:
            printf("Enter a valid choice i.e. from 1 to 11: ");
            goto retake_seed_type;
    }
    printf("\nEnter the number of generations(-1 for infinite): ");
    scanf_s("%d", &generation);
    for (i = 1; i <= generation; i++){
        system("cls");
        neighbour_manager();
        printf("GENERATION NUMBER: %d\n", i);
        generation_printer();
        Sleep(1500);
    }
    if (generation == -1)
    {int z=0;
        while (!_kbhit())
            {
            system("cls");
            neighbour_manager();
            generation_printer();
            z++;
            printf("GENERATION NUMBER: %d\n", z);
            printf("Press any key to stop.\n\n\n\n\n");
            Sleep(1500);
            }

    }
    int choice_after_execution=0;
   printf("\n\nAll generations have been generated.\nPress 1 to Restart.\nPress 2 to Exit.\nYour Choice: ");
   after_generation_valid_choice:
   scanf("%d",&choice_after_execution);
   if(choice_after_execution==1)
    goto start;
   if(choice_after_execution==2)
        {
            printf("Thank you for using this program.");
            Sleep(2000);//for dramatic purposes
            goto exit;//if user decides to exit the program then skip system pause and just exit
        }
   else
    {
        printf("Enter a valid choice: ");
        goto after_generation_valid_choice;
    }

    exit:
    exit(0);
}

void neighbour_manager(){
    int i, j;

    int neighbour;
    for ( i = 0; i < 35; i++){
        for ( j = 0; j < 85; j++){

            neighbour = 0;
            if (array[i - 1 < 0 ? 34 : i - 1][j - 1 < 0 ? 84 : j - 1] == live)   neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[i - 1 < 0 ? 34 : i - 1][j] == live)    neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[i - 1 < 0 ? 34 : i - 1][(j + 1) % 85] == live)    neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[i][j - 1 < 0 ? 84 : j - 1] == live)     neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[i][(j + 1) % 85] == live)     neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[(i + 1) % 35][j - 1 < 0 ? 84 : j - 1] == live) neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[(i + 1) % 35][j] == live) neighbour = neighbour + 1;
            if (array[(i + 1) % 35][(j + 1) % 85] == live) neighbour = neighbour + 1;


            if(neighbour == 3)
            {
                array1[i][j] = live;
            }
            else if (neighbour < 2 || neighbour > 3)
            {
                array1[i][j] = dead;
            }
            else
            {
                array1[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<35; i++){
        for(j=0; j<85; j++){
            array[i][j] = array1[i][j];
            array1[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return;
}


void generation_printer()
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 85; j++) {
            printf("%c", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: `goto` is definitely not the way to go. When you say "build a border of asterisks around the final printed array", do you mean a simple cosmetic change? (i.e. the print will look different but the rules of the game do not change).

Comment: Regarding "double printing", you have to clear your `array` right after the `start:` label (set all elements to space in a double loop). Also, wrapping the pattern (writing to `array[i%35][j%85]` instead to `array[i][j]`) must be done for all patterns, not just for patterns 5 to 10.

Comment: There are some legitimate use cases of `goto`. However, until You decide You have enough experience for independent critical point of view about programming, assume the following: `goto` does not exist.

For example when obtaining the seed type, you use `goto` to repeat operation in case of wrong user input. Use `while` or `do while` instead.

Comment: yes by "build a border of asterisks around the final printed array", i mean just a cosmetic change no change in rules might occur

Comment: Thank you so much Dialecticus. You're a lifesaver. now there is no more double printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slight modification of your `generation_printer()` function that should print a little border around the output:

```
// It's a good idea to extract the size of your grid to constants that you
// can easily tweak.
const int kLineWidth = 85;
const int kLineHeight = 35;

void generation_printer()
{
    int i, j;
    // Top border
    for (i = 0; i < kLineWidth + 2; i++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < kLineHeight; i++) {
        // Star to the beginning of the line
        printf("*");
        // Contents of the line
        for (j = 0; j < kLineWidth; j++) {
            printf("%c", array[i][j]);
        }
        // Star at the end of the line
        printf("*\n");
    }
    // Bottom border
    for (i = 0; i < kLineWidth + 2; i++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Regarding the `goto` statement, there are much cleaner ways to handle control flow! Start by splitting your `main()` into several smaller functions, and use `while` or `do... while` loops to repeat sections in case of invalid choices.

Also, `_kbhit()` is a Windows-specific function and should be replaced so that your code is more portable (i.e. can run on several operating systems).

Comment: There is no portable alternative for `_kbhit` except using a third party code or library like PDCurses. Portability in a school assignment is not exactly a priority anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much @merlinND. Your tweaking is a bit wrong. There should be `kLineHeight` in the first and last for loops other than that it is perfect. All the same you saved my ass so thanks a lot. Also my university has mostly windows PC so `_kbhit` isn't going to be a problem.

Comment: Oh yes you're right I swapped width & height, I think it's fixed now. Glad I could help!